# WPF: ClipboardContentBinding does not work for advanced DataGrid-columns

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, clipboard, datatemplate

I am trying to export my `DataGrid` (name: `myDataGrid`) to .csv - but have ran into some issues.
`<TextColumn>` export as intended, but my `<DataTemplate>` `<ComboBox>` and `<wpfTool:DateTimePicker>` do not. Their cells end up empty.

Here's the `XAML` for the two columns:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <wpfTool:DateTimePicker Value="{Binding PropertyName}"></wpfTool:DateTimePicker>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox SelectedValuePath="{Binding ExampleName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="25" Tag="0" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="15" Tag="1" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="12" Tag="2" />
                <ComboBoxItem Content="6" Tag="3" />
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And my "ExportToCSV"-method:

```
myDataGrid.SelectAllCells();
myDataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, myDataGrid);
string result1 = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);
string result2 = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
myDataGrid.UnselectAllCells();
System.IO.StreamWriter file1 = new("My:\File\Path\test.xls");
file1.WriteLine(result2.Replace(',', ' '));
file1.Close();
```

I have been trying to set up the `ClipboardContentBinding` event,  but could not get it working. I am using `MVVM`, but would be fine with a code behind solution as well.

(I was not able to implement the solution provided in the accepted answer at
[Bind ClipboardContentBinding to DisplayMemberPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149232/bind-clipboardcontentbinding-to-displaymemberpath))

Comment: Clipboard? Why don't you export the *data* from the `ItemsSource`?

Comment: @mm8, I spent the last few hours after I saw your comment implementing this solution: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/09/29/export-data-from-a-datagrid/
But without any apparent error messages or blatant mistakes, my issue remains. It just seems to incredibly complex. If you know of a hacky fix for my problem using the clipboard solution OR a simple way to export from the `ItemsSource`, I'd be grateful.

Comment: So what exact issue do you have after implementing the solution in that blog post? Or what data are you looking to export and how do you want to represent it in the .csv file?

Comment: @mm8, I'm afraid I can't recall - I got rid of all the code, it was way to complex (for me) -- I would prefer the "hackier" solution, if there is one (clipboarding! =D).
In my DataGrid there are decimals, strings (both export fine) and comboboxitems bound to object type (won't export). Also, the DateTimePicker is bound to a string, but it won't export. I just want everything to be represented as simple text in the .csv file.

Comment: So why don't you iterate through the data items?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after a few hours of searching I found the following solution:

```
ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding DetectionTimestamp}"
```

I use using DataBinding, So my XAML changed to:

```
          <DataGridTemplateColumn  SortMemberPath="DetectionTimestamp" 
                    Header="Date" 
                    CanUserSort="true" 
                    ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding DetectionTimestamp}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="DetectionTimestamp"/>
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And now the clipboard contains all cells data and also my export to CSV works fine.